# Finding a closed form for the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (1+ \sum_{j=1}^m j)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to simplify this sigma notation to possible closed notation.
Could anybody please help me with this?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Big(1+\sum_{j=1}^m j \Big)$$

Comment: well I've got the basic idea down for summing up here. I can read this as 1 + the sum of j to integer m. all starting with i. which is 1 up to integer n. I've been able to do the preceeding questions, but this one just kind of stumped me. Anything helps! thank you

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^mj\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{m(m+1)}2\right)=n\left(1+\frac{m(m+1)}2\right)=\frac{n(m^2+m+2)}{2}$$